# How to calculate the phase angle between satellite and sun with the use of skyfield

Tags: artificial-satellite, python, visibility-of-spacecraft, skyfield

With the discussion that took place on answer(s) to  [How to calculate cone angle between two satellites given their look angles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26286/12102)  I would like to ask if my proposal solving that question works like intended:

```
sun = ephemeris['sun']
earth = ephemeris['earth']
vecObserverSat = (s1 - loc).at(tEv)
vecObsserverSun = (sun - (earth + loc)).at(tEv)
phase = vecObserverSat.separation_from(vecObserverSun)
```

Comment: You may find some helpful information in Astronomy SE in answers to [Calculating the apparent magnitude of a satellite](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28744/7982) and [Venus' magnitude during inferior conjunction](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33797/7982) and [What is the difference between albedo, absolute magnitude or apparent magnitude?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29449/7982) and [Why is Enceladus's albedo greater than 1?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20795/7982)

Comment: I vote to close this question because the context explained in the body of the question does not match the question itself. To me, the linkage with the previous question ("cone angle between two satellites") is not well explained.

Comment: Sorry about the mismatch, I corrected the question

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks